# How to use OnLastRecord and Next in crystal report to powerbi report builder

Tags: powerbi, crystal-reports, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

How to convert the below crystal code to powerbi report builder. PREVIOUS  I know it is available in report builder but below I am trying to translate

```
Not OnLastRecord and  Next ({ColumnA}) = {ColumnA})
```